# Converting python to ruby params issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm converting some python code to ruby. It's going ok so far, except I'm running into some issues with parameters. The python code is:

```
def sign_policy(policy):
  signed_policy = base64.b64encode(policy)
  signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(
    app.config.get('AWS_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY'), signed_policy, hashlib.sha1).
    digest())
  return { 'policy': signed_policy, 'signature': signature }

def sign_headers(headers):
  headers = bytearray(headers, 'utf-8')  # hmac doesn't want unicode
  return {
    'signature': base64.b64encode(hmac.new(
        app.config.get('AWS_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY'), headers, hashlib.sha1).
        digest())
  }

def s3_signature():
  request_payload = request.get_json()
  if request_payload.get('headers'):
      response_data = sign_headers(request_payload['headers']) 
  else:
      response_data = sign_policy(request.data)
  return jsonify(response_data)
```

My ruby version so far is:

```
def create
  puts params[:headers]
  if params[:headers].present?
    response_data = sign_headers(params[:headers]) 
  else
    response_data = sign_policy(params)
  end
  render json: response_data
end

private

def sign_policy(policy)
  signed_policy = Base64.encode64(policy).gsub("\n","")

  signature = Base64.encode64(
    OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(
      OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha1'), 
      AWS_SECRET_KEY, signed_policy)
  ).gsub("\n","")

  return { 'policy': signed_policy, 'signature': signature }
end

def sign_headers(headers)
  #headers = bytearray(headers, 'utf-8')
  return {
    'signature':  Base64.encode64(
    OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(   
      AWS_SECRET_KEY, headers, OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha1')
    ))
  }
end
```

I'm running into the following issue: `no implicit conversion of ActionController::Parameters into String`, which makes it obvious whats wrong (Params is a hash and it needs to be a string)..However, what is being passed in the python code? I'm missing what I should be passing?

Comment: Yeah the ruby code is happening inside a rails controller

Comment: @SebastiánPalma, Wouldn't `Base64.encode64(params[:policy]) just lead to the same error? Currently I'm just passing it in as a variable.

Comment: It is, however, in the create method of my controller, I'm grabbing the params and passing it to the sign_policy function. The variable policy in my sign_policy function should be a hash of all the request parameters I believe.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma, that's what I'm a little confused about. In the python code, doesn't it seem like it's passing the entire parameter request? The params I'm receiving don't have a key for "policy".

Comment: I actually just figured it out. `request.data` in flask returns a string. In ruby, I just had to convert the params to a string. Since you led me down the problem solving track, if you add an answer I'll accept it @SebastiánPalma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you need to pass a single value, String or any other, it depends on the data type you need to pass to use `Base64.encode64(policy)`.

As you're passing `params[:headers]` in the `sign_headers` method call, in the case of the `sign_policy` call, you're passing `params` which is the whole `ActionController::Parameters`, try debugging the values you sent on `params` to send the needed value.